Performance difference between hybrid mpi/openmp and pure mpi
I have tested a simple hybrid mpi/openmp programming:
void  mpi_openmp_run ()
{
   double t00 = MPI_Wtime();   

   for(std::size_t tit=0; tit<1000; ++tit)
   {
    
    int tid ;
    
    double t0, t1;
    
    #pragma omp parallel private(tid, t0, t1)
    {
      
        t0 = MPI_Wtime();

        #pragma omp for
        for(std::size_t zindex=0; zindex<10000000000; zindex++)    
            {
                    tid = omp_get_thread_num();

            }      
  
        t1 = MPI_Wtime(); 

        #pragma omp barrier 
        if(tid==0)
        {
            std::cout <<" Multithread wall clock: "<<<< t1-t0<<" in threads: " << omp_get_thread_num()<<std::endl;
        }
        
    }

   double t11=MPI_Wtime();   


    if(myrank==0)
    {
        printf("Wall Clock = %15.6f\n",t11-t00);
    }
}

I tested the code with 2 cpus * 2 threads, I got
running time for each thread is about 2.062, and total time is 404.56
If I use only 1 cpu + 4 threads, I got
running time for each thread is about 1.039, and total time is 202.79
I wonder why there is a difference of factor about 2, since in this simple example, there is no communications among cpus.
In this test, I have basically allocated the same number of computational resources (2*2=4). Shall this bring the same performance? This is really confusing for me.

a MPI tasks is running 10000000000 iterations, so the elapsed time should only depend on the number of threads per MPI task, and the number of MPI tasks should be irrelevant.

yes, i have forgot to divide the iterations by factor 2 when using two MPI stasks. This will produce correct timing 204.90 for 2 cpus * 2 threads.

A very general confusion for me:  If there seems no difference between hybrid mpi/openmp and pure mpi with respect to performance. Is it a good idea and practical to use only pure mpi instead of hybrid mpi/openmp, regarding performance issue? In which situation, one will outperform the other?

Pure MPI has no intrinsic reason to be slower if you don't need interprocess communication at all (but I would say then that in this case MPI is not needed at all and the parallelism can be handled by launching N times the same executable)

As usual it depends. Keep in mind memory overhead is more important with MPI (it can be an issue on nodes with many cores and not so much memory) and depending on the app and/or dataset, it might be easier to unlock an other level of parallelism with OpenMP.

Thanks all for the very useful comments. To keep my code flexible, would it be a good idea to write a hybrid mpi/openmp code. With this code, if needed,  by setting the number of multi-threads to be 1, we can still run the hybrid code as pure MPI. Otherwise, we can run the code in a hybrid mode as usual by choosing number of mpi staks and number of multi-threads.  I am not sure if this is practical?

Your loop does nothing and can be optimized out by the compiler assuming you enabled optimization (you should really for a benchmark). What compiler optimizations are enabled? Please use a more realistic benchmark. Besides, what is your exact CPU reference? How threads are bound to core and are they bound to core? OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE can help to get information about that as well as vendor specific variables. Which OpenMP and MPI implementation do you use? Critical details are missing.

This seems rather complex for me, I tried to run the code with "mpirun --bind-to none -np 2 ./test"  Does this mean my threads are not bounded to any core?   I have 0-23 cpus with inform for each , e.g.,                                                                               processor :23
vendor_id :GenuineIntel
cpu family :6
model  : 151
model name : 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-12900K
stepping : 2
microcode : 0x32
cpu MHz  : 800.000
cache size : 30720 KB
physical id : 0
siblings : 24
core id  : 39
cpu cores : 16
apicid  : 78
initial apicid : 78

This is a two steps tango: first bind the MPI task to the right number of cores, then ask the OpenMP runtime to bind each thread to a single core.

Before trying to fix the issue we need to analyse what is happening to check if the thread-binding is actually the source of the issue. You can ask the OpenMP implementation to do that but without the target implementation we cannot help you on this. You can also use hwloc-ps for that. Note the provided technical output in the above comment is barely readable and it is better to add this in the question as an update.

Your actual problem is solved, but I thought I'd offer some thoughts on hybrid computing.

It is very hard to make a toy example where hybrid outperforms pure MPI.
If you have a very irregular workload, using OpenMP dynamic schedule may spread the work in a way that MPI can not.
If you have a cluster, and a large core count (I have machines with 50-100 cores per node) pure MPI generates many small messages, whereas hybrid generates one large. This may make a difference, though it's not immediately clear in what direction.
MPI can have a larger memory demand if all processes need access to the same dataset, where OpenMP would have that in shared memory, but you can counteract that by using MPI shared memory.

